# setting RoundRect shape Boarder to image view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I am using this following code to set a boarder to `UIImageView`.

my code is:

```
[imageview.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor orangeColor] CGColor]];
                [imageview.layer setBorderWidth: 6.0];
```

It looking a rectangle shape boarder.However I need a RoundRect shape for my image view Boarder or want curves in edges of `UIImageView` boarder. Can any one tell me a good way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Following Lines:

```
[imageSubview.layer setCornerRadius:10.0];
[imageSubview.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider Jeff LaMarche's RoundedRectView class useful.

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/11/creating-transparent-uiviews-rounded.html